# C([0,1]) is a path connected topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}$ with the euclidean topology e let $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ the set of continuos function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. On $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$, we define the metric

$d(f,g)=\max\limits_{x\in [0,1]}\{|f(x)-g(x)|\}$.

Prove that $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ with the topology induced by the metric $d$ is path connected.

I made an attempt more functional style than topological, however, here it is.

Let $T:[0,1]\to \mathcal{C}([0,1])$ defined by $T(t)=f(x)-t(f(x)-g(x))$.

The metric $d$ is induced by the 1 norm on $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$, so, I can prove that $T$ is continuos showing that if $t_n$ is a convergent sequence in $[0,1]$ (let $t$ its limits), then $T(t_n)$ converges to $T(t)$.

So, $||T(t_n)-T(t)||_1=||f(x)-t_n(f(x)-g(x))-f(x)+t(f(x)-g(x))||_1\leq ||(t_n-t)(f(x)-g(x))||_1=|t_n-t|||f(x)-g(x)||_1 \longrightarrow 0$

because the convergence of $t_n$ and the fact that $f-g$ is a bounded function because is continuous on a compact (Weierstrass).

In conclusion, $T$ is continuous and it's an arc, so, the thesis follows.

Is it correct? Is there a more topological approach?

Comment: Every normed vector space is path connected.

Comment: @AnneBauval ... with the same proof as this.

Comment: More generally: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298389

Comment: Uh, thanks! I didn't know it was valid more generally on any normed space.  So, could we consider  $C([0,1])$ as a normed space with the norm 1, even without setting that metric d?